# Why angular $route.current.params is empty?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have made provider for holding some settings data and among them are URL query parameters.
Here is the code:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .provider('settings', function(){
    this.$get = function($route, $location){
      var p1 = $route.current.params.param1;
      var p2 = $route.current.params.param2;
      return {
        param1: p1,
        param2: p2
      };
    };
  });
```

But `$route.current.param` is empty and I am wondering why?
In order to access query params I need to use something like this function:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    if(!window || !window.location || !window.location.search){
        return undefined;
    }
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

My question is why `$route.current.params` is empty?

Here is interesting info I have found meanwhile:

When accessing via url http://localhost:9000/?param1=aaa&param2=bbb
then  `$route.current.params` is `empty`, but when accesing via url http://localhost:9000/#?param1=aaa&param2=bbb 
then  `$route.current.params` is `NOT empty`.

So adding `#` before question mark makes difference!

Still not clear why.

Comment: You can inject $routeParams and get as $routeParams.param1 and $routeParams.param2

Comment: In such case I param1 is undefined.
console.log($routeParams); gives empty object: Object {}

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Why don't you just forget about this provider (which can't possibly work: a provider is only called once, when the application starts, and route params change all the time), and just inject $routeParams, or $route?

Comment: For my case this is fine - there some initialization settings reading only once. So would like to know why "#" is required to have $route.current.params not empty?

Comment: Because route params give the parameters of the current route by analyzing the $location, and if the $location hasn't been configured to use html5 mode, everything happens after the `#`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location. It seems you want to use an angular service to get query parameters which are not related to the angular application, but just happen to be query parameters of the base URL from which you load the app. Why do you have more than one URL to load the app in the first place, and why is it parameterized?

Comment: Your comment helped me to find answer. You can post something like 


in order to use $route.current.params to parse url there 2 options:
1) Purt app in the HTML5 mode
or
2) If the app in the hashbang mode then refactor url tpo be "hashbang compliant", in other words, put hash before question mark.


and I will accept your response. Thanks.